# Why curl errors: https in not supported or disabled

Tags: ssl, curl, https, libcurl

I'm using php-curl but it errors:

> https is not supported or disabled

I even tried installing it in this way:

```
./configure --with-ssl
make
sudo make install
```

But it still says https is disabled.
How can i fix it?